# How to solve this with gamma and beta function

Tags: calculus

I can't solve this, no matter how I try

[image]

Comment: So, what did you try ?

Comment: i tried to put (x=u\1+u)   to change the determenant to 0 and infinity and slove it with beta function but i cant reshape the problem to be like beta function famous formula

Comment: I think it could be good you include in the post everything you tried. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $x=\dfrac1t~.~$ Now all that's left to do is evaluating $2I=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}~,~$  which can be done by substituting $u=\dfrac1{1+t^4}.$

Comment: Lucian can you explain more please

Comment: @user297497: What do you get after you do the substitution ?

Comment: when you sustitute x=1\t then when x=0 ...t=infinity and when x=1...t=1..

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4BK2W.png that what it reached

Comment: @user297497: So you do agree that $2I=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}$ ?

Comment: no lucian i dont agree i cant know how did you reach from the obve question to these formula

Comment: @user297497: Do you agree that, in general, $\displaystyle\int_a^bf(x)~dx+\int_b^cf(x)~dx~=~\int_a^cf(x)~dx$ ?

Comment: yes off course i agree

Comment: @user297497: Then we agree that $I+I=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}~,~$ correct ?

Comment: do you mean wat written in the picture   [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/PZ78L.png   worng it worng the determenat is different you cant say that

Comment: @user297497: Let $a=0,~b=1,~c=\infty,$ and $f(t)=\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+t^4}}$